# Can you save an image into static folder dynamically?

Tags: python, html

I have a Python app that takes a photo from the webcam and after processing it saves in a folder. I want to display a new photo in html, but only photos from 'static' folder are seen on the page. Can I save it into different folder and then use it?

```
<a target="_blank" href="static/images/map.jpg">
   <img src="static/images/map.jpg" alt="map">
</a>
```

[image]

When I save into the static folder, I have to refresh the page, because the previous photo is shown.

Comment: Not sure if a python issue or a webserver issue... Clarify more please. Are you using a framework?

Comment: I use flask. I want to display photo sent from server into html

Comment: If you update a file on disk the web browser viewing it has no way of knowing this file has changed. You could write a bit of JS to reload the image periodically which would just re-display the image but not reload the entire page.

Comment: Do you know how I can write it in JS?